# Creating a SQLITE table with a fixed number of items

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am creating a database where I will store some statistics about the battery. 
Everytime the battery drops 1 percent, I want to add a row to my sqlite database with some info.

This is working pretty well, but with time, this table is becoming really huge.

What I would like to do is to set a maximum number of records (let's say 100 for instance).

Is that possible to set the number of records in my table or will I need to check this table everytime and clean it by code?

Here is my code:

```
create table batterystat (_id integer primary key autoincrement, value integer not null, ....)
```

And my query

```
public Cursor fetchAllStats{
   return db.query(databaseName,myColumns,null,null,null,null,null);
}
```

Thank a lot for any help.

**NOTE:**
"you will have to do that by yourself and delete the extra rows by code" may be a correct answer if that is the case :-p

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit an sqlite Table's Maximum Number of Rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035670/limit-an-sqlite-tables-maximum-number-of-rows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a trigger and a delete query like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER batterystat_trigger AFTER INSERT ON batterystat 
BEGIN 
    DELETE FROM batterystat where _id NOT IN (SELECT _id from batterystat ORDER BY insertion_date DESC LIMIT 100)
END
```