# Best strategy for storing dynamic data

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, twitter

I am developing a twitter client for android.
I'm doing this a practice project and I need some help regarding storing the tweets in the timeline.

Can anyone suggest the best strategy for storing the tweets in the timeline?

What I need to do is to store the tweets in the database:

- a max of 50 tweets
- when newer tweets are available then add newer ones
- but still making sure that the elements in the database does not
  exceed 50

And also I intend to set an expiration date for the tweets, that is to delete all the tweets in db if not updated for a certain amount of time.

I specifically don't need code. Just a strategy/algorithm to get me on the right path. What do the apps in the android market employ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it would be the best to write a database trigger which would remove oldest entry upon inserting a new record, if total record count exceeds 50.
Shouldn't be that hard, since almost all databases support database triggers.

Comment: Ohh...okay did not know about triggers...thanks for the info...will try it out... :)

Answer (score 0):

I just answered this question for someone else.  Use a trigger like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096140/creating-a-sqlite-table-with-a-fixed-number-of-items/9100140)