# android sqlite create table size trigger

Tags: android, sqlite, triggers

How can I create a insert trigger in sqlite? I should check if the number of rows is < 5 = ok. If the number of rows is 5 = delete first row.
Is this way of collecting garbage efficient?

Comment: You should show some code to see what you have done. So others can understand your question or topic better.

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096140/creating-a-sqlite-table-with-a-fixed-number-of-items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is quite good: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html

You should end up with something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER rowlimit5
  AFTER INSERT ON table
  BEGIN
     DELETE FROM table WHERE ROWID NOT IN (
       SELECT ROWID FROM table ORDER BY ROWID DESC LIMIT 5
     );
  END;
```