# database maximum of 10 and sort according to score, and delete the replacement of the score if it is the lowest

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Hi guys im creating game and im new in sql lite. i have a code for inserting database but i dont know how to maximum it at 10 and also i dont know how to compare the new score of the player to the older scores. also how can i delete in the top 10 scored the lowest if the new score beat 1 of the top 10 score.  im looking for great codes with good explanation so that i will understand the flow of codes.

Heres my database class:

```
        public class highscore {

 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "topscoredb";
 private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "tablescore";
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
 public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
 public static final String KEY_SCORE = "score";
 public static final String KEY_NAME = "players_name";

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;


private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{



        public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                     KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                     KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT  NULL, " +
                     KEY_SCORE + " TEXT NOT NULL);"

                );

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
                int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST" + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);

        }
 }



   public highscore(Context c){
  ourContext = c;
  }

 public highscore open() throws SQLException{
 ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
 ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();


  return this;

 }

  public void close(){
   ourHelper.close();

    }



   public long createEntry(String name, String tscore) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

  ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
  cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
  cv.put(KEY_SCORE, tscore);
 return  ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}

 public String getData() {
String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_SCORE};
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,null, null);
String result = "";

int irow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
int iname = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
int iscore = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SCORE);

for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
    result = result + c.getString(irow)+ " " +c.getString(iname)+" "+ 
c.getString(iscore) + "\n";
     }

return result;
    }

    }
```

should i use method?

Comment: A similar kind of answer is already on stackoverflow.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035670/limit-an-sqlite-tables-maximum-number-of-rows?rq=1

Comment: somehow similar but it was different in coding in android

Answer (score 1):

well android uses sqlite and you can use the solution in [Limit an sqlite Table's Maximum Number of Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035670/limit-an-sqlite-tables-maximum-number-of-rows?rq=1).

You can also get the results in descending order

```
ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,null,KEYSCORE + " DESC");
```

and show top 10 results.

or use SQlite query builder method to limit the results 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html#query(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,null,KEYSCORE + " DESC"); is this for database that has no data? it was epic fail to my code.. i know that the desc is for descending but how about the name of the player. theres something wrong in the code that you suggest

Answer (score -1):

we can store the all the scores in Database and write a write a query get the first ten highest scores...

select * from ( select empno , sal , rank() over (order by sal desc) as rnk  from emp where rnk <= 5);

Comment: can you further explain to me. post some example.

Comment: simple thing  we have only one table..insert the every thing means all scores but while showing time get the only ten top records.

Comment: This does not work in SQLite.